# Headphones not detecting in Windows 7 64 Bit HP laptop

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers, 64-bit

I have recently installed windows 7 64 bit on my HP laptop. I have download from [this](https://www.getmyos.com/windows-7-ultimate-32-64-bit) link. The issue I am facing is I am not able to configure the laptop to detect headphone.

I tied to go to device manager and tried to update driver from there but it is says it is up to date.

[image: device manager]

I  have downloaded the sp48147 audio driver from HP site. But when I install that driver, it is only allowing the headphone. It is closing the laptop speakers. When I uninstall it, laptop automatically download the high definition audio driver and again it doesn't detect the headphones.

My pc was detecting the audio drivers earlier. Earlier I had windows 8. But for some development software were not compatible with that, so I need to install windows 7 64 bit.

Can anyone provide any solution?